# Swift 4 One View Controller two views hide navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, uiview

I have one View Controller and this View Controller contains two views/scenes in the main.storybard. 
I am trying to hide the top navigation bar at first view/scene, but unhide it again on the second view/scene. 
I tried with

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

But this will only work with two View Controller classes.

Does anyone have a idea to manage it?

Comment: Hey how you can hide and show 1 view to 2 view?

Answer (score 0):

Hide navigationbar in `viewWillAppear` & unhide in `viewWillDisappear`

```
var shouldHideNavBar = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(shouldHideNavBar, animated: animated)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if shouldHideNavBar == true {
             navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
        }
}
```

And when you perform segue set `shouldHideNavBar` as `true`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "show") {
        let viewController = segue!.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        viewController.shouldHideNavBar = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I call the functions for only one of the two views? Like viewWillAppear(true) for the second view and viewWillDisappear(true) for the first view?

Comment: how the two views are switched?

Comment: In the main.storyboard interface builder with ctrl + pull to the second view and then  action segue is "show"

Comment: so you have two view controllers?

Comment: Yeah, two views, but only one ViewControllerclass.swift  . So one class for two view Controllers

Answer (score 0):

You should use extra control. Or you can create an IBInspactable variable and assing it's value on Interface Builder. Like this:

```
@IBDesignable class myViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBInspectable var isNavbarHidden: Bool = true{
        didSet{
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = isNavBarHidden
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //I am not sure if this line is necessary
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = isNavBarHidden
    }
}
```

After then go to InterfaceBuilder(your storyboard file) and set its value for your Scenes on your viewControllers properties.

Comment: Where exactly and in what form do I set this value in the Storyboard

Comment: Select your controller in storyboard. Then, on right panel select attributes inspector(where you set your view's properties like label's text) you will see isNavigationBarHidden property on here. If you want to hide navigation bar, you should select 'on', otherwise 'off'. Cause of default value is true, as default, your navbar will be hidden