# How to setNavigationBarHidden only on two of the three viewControllers under one tabBar controller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm using a tabBar controller to control three viewControllers and want to set the navigationBar hidden only on two viewControllers, but it's not working.

[picture of the structure of the tabBarController and three controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHspP.png)
This is the current tabBarController and viewControllers. I have a viewController for my tabBar Controller, and I set a navigationBar on that viewController

```
class PlayerTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNavBar()
    }
    
    func configureNavBar() {
        let backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 10))
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "leave 1"), for: .normal)
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onBackPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        let barBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackButton
    }

    @objc func onBackPressed() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

TeamViewController is the screen that I want to show the navBar, so I'm not doing anything to that viewController, and I'm using this code to hide the navBar in other two controllers(timerView and rankingView)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }
```

The problem is that when I go to one of the two controllers, the navBar is hidden, but the navBar is visible when I move between the two screens(timer and ranking). For example, when I go to the timer or ranking screen from team screen, it works. But when I move from timer to ranking, the navBar is visible on the ranking screen and vice versa. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Sounds like it happens due to the call on `viewWillDisappear` when you're switching controllers. I'd suggest hiding the navigation bar permanently and including a `UIView` top bar on that specific controller instead of the nav bar as you prefer keeping it hidden otherwise

Comment: does these answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845583/iphone-hide-navigation-bar-only-on-first-page, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767122/swift-4-one-view-controller-two-views-hide-navigation-bar/51767420, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36543349/20452635

Comment: Sorry but can you explain in more detail about including a UIView top bar on the specific controller?